# C++ "cin" only reads the first word

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class String
{
    char str[100];
    public:
    void input()
    {
        cout<<"Enter string :";
        cin>>str;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<str;
    }
};

int main()
{
     String s;
     s.input();
     s.display();
     return 0;
}
```

I am working in Turbo C++ 4.5. The code is running fine but its not giving the desired output
for e.g if i give input as "steve hawking" only "steve" is being displayed. Can anyone please help?

Comment: The line `cin<<str` won't even compile. And why is this tagged `c` and `java`?

Comment: Why are you using a 20 year old IDE? There's a plethora of more modern free IDE's with better compilers (NetBeans, Eclipse, Visual Studio Express, etc.).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `>>` on a stream reads one word at a time. To read a whole line into a `char` array:

```
cin.getline(str, sizeof str);
```

Of course, once you've learnt how to implement a string, you should use `std::string` and read it as

```
getline(cin, str);
```

It would also be a very good idea to get a compiler from this century; yours is over 15 years old, and C++ has changed significantly since then. Visual Studio Express is a good choice if you want a free compiler for Windows; other compilers are available.

Answer (score 4):

```
cin>>str;
```

This only reads in the next token. In C++ iostreams, tokens are separated by whitespace, so you get the first word.

You probably want [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/), which reads an entire line into a string:

```
getline(cin, str);
```

Comment: so how to get the whole sentence as output ?

Comment: It's 'cin>>str' not 'cin<<str'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
   cin.read( str, sizeof(str) );
```

But, this will fill up the buffer. Instead you should use cin.getLine() as MikeSeymour suggested

Comment: `read` will fill the whole buffer; you want `getline` to read until the end of the line.

Comment: You are right, it will fill the whole buffer.

Comment: `std::noskipws` doesn't do what you imply. It only affects the *initial* whitespace, not the terminating white space.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cin.getline to read the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
cin.getline(cin, str);
```